# How can I create a Settings page in a Sphinx documentation?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-sphinx

I would like to create a "Settings" page in my documentation created using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/), similar to the one in [the discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

[image: a popup showing options for fonts and themes]

I only ask for making the settings shown in the image above: font, and theme. So how would I do it? Must I use extensions or manually add HTML to the built documentation files everytime I build them?

Please help me and thank you.